# How to identify using xsl whether a node exists in my xml?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this xml

```
<game>
 <genre>
  <action>...</action>
  <racing>...</racing>
 <price>
..
..
 </price>
</genre>
</game>
```

I want to check whether price node is present in the xml using xsl. how can I do that? if **price** node is present then call a particular `template` else call another `template`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply call `xsl:apply-templates` with the match attribute set to the element name. If the element exists the template is called. It it does not exist, the template won't be called.
If you are trying to build a if-else statement you could check the existence like this

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="boolean(price)">
        <!-- do something -->
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <!-- do something else -->
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

So you can check for existence of an element and react accordingly.

Comment: Some docs on this: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-boolean  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256159.aspx